# Rails 5 - find_or_create_by with nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I'm trying to create a new object with its associated records in the same form but would like the associated records to use `find_or_create_by` instead of just create (as the associated model records may and most of the time already will exist). I have spent the last two days digging through every post and article that I can find related to this subject trying to get this to work but still my form tries to create the new object only, not search for existing.

**Models**

```
#order.rb
has_many :order_owners, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :order
has_many :owners, through: :order_owners

accepts_nested_attributes_for :order_owners

#owner.rb
has_many :order_owners, dependent: :destroy
has_many :orders, through: :order_owners
validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false } 

#order_owner.rb
belongs_to :owner
belongs_to :order

accepts_nested_attributes_for :owner
```

**Form**

**`orders/new.html.erb`**

```
<%= bootstrap_form_for(@orders, layout: :horizontal, label_col: "col-sm-2", control_col: "col-sm-6") do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

  ...

  <%= f.fields_for :order_owners do |orderowner| %>

    <%= render 'orders/new_order_owners', f: orderowner, render_partial: 'orders/new_order_owners' %>

  <% end %>

  ...

  <%= f.form_group do %>
    <%= f.submit "Create Order", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <%= link_to_add_association fa_icon("plus", text: "Add Owner"), f, :order_owners,
                                  class: "btn btn-outline pull-right #{orderBtnDisable(@properties)}", partial: "orders/new_order_owners", id: "newOrderOwnerAdd" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**`orders/new_order_owners` partial**

```
<div class="m-t-md m-b-md border-bottom form-horizontal nested-fields">

  <%= link_to_remove_association(fa_icon("remove", text: ""), f, { class: "btn btn-danger btn-outline pull-right" }) %>

  <% f.object.build_owner unless f.object.owner %>

  <%= f.fields_for :owner do |owner| %>
    <%= owner.select :name, options_from_collection_for_select(@owners, "name", "name"),
               { label: "Name:", include_blank: true }, { id: "orderPropOwnerSelect", data: { placeholder: "Select an existing Owner or type a new one.."} } %>
  <% end %>

</div>
```

**Controller**

**`orders/new`**

```
def new
  @order = Order.new
  @order.build_property
  @order.order_owners.build.build_owner
  @properties = Property.find_by_id(params[:property_id])
  if @properties
    @owners = @properties.owners
  else
    @owners = []
  end
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js
  end
end
```

**`orders/create`**

```
def create
  @properties = Property.find(params[:order][:property_id])
  @order = @properties.orders.create(order_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { if @order.save
                    if params[:order][:owners_attributes]
                      order_prop_owner_check(@order, @properties)
                    end
                    flash[:success] = "Order created successfully!"
                    redirect_to property_order_path(@properties, @order)
                  else
                    @properties
                    @owner = @properties.owner
                    render 'new'
                  end
    }
    format.js {
                  if @order.save
                    flash.now[:success] = "Order Updated Successfully!"
                  else
                    flash.now[:danger] = @order.errors.full_messages.join(", ")
                  end
    }
  end
end
```

So as you can see in the `new` action, I instantiate the new Order, build its associated property (its what the Order belongs_to), build the new order_owner relationship, and build the owner for that relationship. Then on submit it creates the order via @properties.orders.create(order_params).

The error that I get is "Order owners owner name already exists." so clearly its not looking up an owner by name. **I have tried:**

- Redefining `autosave_associated_records_for_owner` in order.rb and order_owner.rb, using both belongs_to and has_many variations, but it seems like they never get called so I must be doing something wrong. (I have tried variations of almost every answer I could find on SO)
- `before_add:` callback on both `has_many :owners, through: :order_owners` and `has_many :order_owners` in order.rb.
- Extending `has_many :owners` and `has_many :owners, through: :order_owners` in order.rb as well as `belongs_to :owner` in order_order.rb

I've also tried different variations of calling associations and such within the form so I must be just misunderstanding something. I'm also using Cocoon to manage the nested forms but I've talked to the author on unrelated issues and Cocoon is essentially just a view helper for nested forms so the solution must something in the models/controller.

Any and all ideas welcome. Thanks in advance.

P.s. I left code in the controller actions that may/may not pertain to this exact post but I wanted to show the entire action for completeness. If it matters, I manually set the owners select via AJAX when a property is selected in another field. Basically it just looks up the property and adds existing owners to the owners select.

Comment: To confirm, is the `OrderOwner` table meant to be a joins table? i.e., it really only has the id's of orders and id's of owners?, Additionally, can you add your routes?

Comment: Also, sorry if I'm being dense here, but at what point exactly are you calling `.find_or_create_by`?

Comment: Hey, apologies for the delay in response, spent all day traveling. Yes `OrderOwner` is a joins table/model with only `order_id` and `owner_id`. Currently, I'm not calling `find_or_create_by` at any point because I can't get it to work. Ideally, I'd like to have it called when an Owner is created via the nested attributes of Order. From everything I've found, it seems like `autosave_associated_records_for_owner` in the OrderOwner table (so I think) should be my ticket but I can't get that to work. Which set of routes should I post? Orders?

Answer (score 2):

The owner is nested inside the order. So when you call order.save, it runs all validations (including owner's). If you want to use `find_or_create_by` you need to do it inside a `before_save`, so you can make modifications to the owner before the validation hits.

```
#order.rb

before_save :find_or_create_owner

def find_or_create_owner
  self.order_owners.each do |order_owner|
    order_owner.owner = Owner.find_or_create_by(name: final_owner.name)
  end
end
```

Further customization may be needed depending on your form and business logic, but that's the main concept.